# Read specific information from the "echo" command while printing and ignoring others

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I am writing some bash scripts and I am faced with the following problem. Let's say:

```
function echo_ignore_print()
{
    echo "ignoring this print" # print this line for the user without storing its value
    value=187fef
    echo "$value" # return this value
}

info_to_keep=$(echo_ignore_print)

echo "$info_to_keep"   #   ignoring this print 187fef
```

I need to be able to print "ignoring this print" as soon as the script gets to that line but I also need to return the value of the variable "$value" by itself, so I can use it later on. I would rather not have global variables.

Therefore, is there a way to king of dump all the string of the echo command and save some for later? or any other way to do this?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The right thing to do is use `echo "ignoring this print" >&2`, so that line goes to a different file descriptor (in this case, standard error). (Posting as a comment because I don't know if modifying the function itself is an option.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write to-be-ignored stuff on `stderr` instead of `stdout`:

```
echo_ignore_print() {
   echo "ignoring this print" >&2
   value='187fef'
   echo "$value"
}

info_to_keep=$(echo_ignore_print)
ignoring this print

echo "$info_to_keep"
187fef
```